# Why is the following query unsupported for change notification?

Tags: oracle, .net-core, odp.net

I'm trying to write some .NET code to listen for changes in an Oracle DB from a subset of users, by registering an `OracleDependency` on the Oracle `UNIFIED_AUDIT_TABLE`. I've defined an audit policy `TEST_AUDIT_POLICY` to audit changes from the users I'm interested in. The following code is my .NET listener:

```
    private const string TableName = "UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL";
    private const string SelectStatement = "select event_timestamp from " + TableName;

    ...

    public Form1()
    {
        var connection = new OracleConnection(Constr);
        connection.Open();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        try
        {
            var dependency = new OracleDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += NotifyTypesChanged;

            command.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
            command.BindByName = true;
            command.CommandText = SelectStatement;

            new OracleDataAdapter(command)
                {MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey}.Fill(DataSet, TableName);
            _dataGrid1.SetDataBinding(DataSet, TableName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following exception:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-29973: Unsupported query or operation  during change notification registration
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
```

Am I unable to listen for changes on `UNIFIED_AUDIT_TABLE` because `UNIFIED_AUDIT_TABLE` is not a table, but just a view? If so, how can I register to be notified of changes against the `TEST_AUDIT_POLICY` policy?

Comment: you have not registered port. And why don't you try to see first if this works with `executenonquery`. First see if this is not related to `DataAdapter`

Comment: This code works for tables other than UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL.

Comment: are you looged in as `sys`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use QCN with views.

see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS576